# How to generate a well distributed normal distribution with a Sobol sequence in c++?

Tags: c++, sequence, normal-distribution, seeding

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
// #include "halton.cpp"
#include "sobol.cpp"

int main()
{
  int n=5000;
  double* thisV;
  thisV = i8_sobol_generate(1,n,0);

  std::mt19937 generator;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0,1.0);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    generator.seed(thisV[i]);
    std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I have generated a low discrepancy sequence using the following code on this [site (Sobol)](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/sobol/sobol.html).
I use it to seed the generator. But the output is some kind of weird. Can someone help me?

Output:

```
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
1.12279
0.302805
...
```

Comment: Are values in `thisV[i]` correct?

Comment: I don't have your libraries installed, but I can tell you that seeding the generator each iteration is probably not what you want to do. Seed it once and let it run it's course. If you insist on using your own generator, don't bother going through `std::mt19937` and implement your own generator class.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek: Yes, the thisV has a correct sobol sequence.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: I think you gave me the right way to go. Are there some information about implementing its own generator class?

Comment: It turns out that you cannot generate your custom distribution from Sobol sequences with the normal (efficient) ways of the C++ distributions. You have to use other more primitive methods. See my answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222538/122461

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the contents of the sobol.cpp file I can't tell you why you gets these exact numbers,
*however*
you re-seed the generator each time you go round the loop.

With the

```
  std::mt19937 generator;
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(0,1.0);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    generator.seed(thisV[i]); //<------------
    std::cout << distribution(generator) << std::endl;
  }
```

if the seed alternates between two values you will get the behaviour you are seeing.

By the way - it is usual to `#include` a head file (rather than a cpp file) while including the cpp file in you rmake file/project.

---

Furthermore, if you look at how you call the code,

```
thisV = i8_sobol_generate(1,n,0);
```

we haven't clarified what the parameters mean.

If you follow the link you have, there are some tests (woot!) with the source code.
One, called, tests sorbol08, and loops as follows:

for ( dim_num = 2; dim_num <= DIM_MAX; dim_num++ )
{             //^----------
seed = 0;

```
// <snip>

for ( i = 0; i <= 110; i++ )
{
  seed_in = seed;
  i8_sobol ( dim_num, &seed, r );

// ....
```

The function you call,

```
double *i8_sobol_generate ( int m, int n, int skip )
```

is sending 1 as the first parameter. This calls the testing function, using this value.

I suspect you should therefore try a higher dimension - it is indeed cycling very quickly.

Do include the .hpp file instead of the cpp file.
Look at the tests for clues about usage.

Comment: The problem is thats I am not really sure how to use the sobol sequence to generate this well distributed normal distribution.

Comment: On reflection I haven't specifically answered that question.